# How can I tell Babel to ignore an es6 import when using the Rollup Babel plugin?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules, rollupjs

Is there any way for me to tell babel to ignore certain imports, for example i don't want babel to touch any es5 imports like polyfills.

I have tried the exclude option but it doesn't do anything. Here are my dev dependancies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.2.0",
    "rollup": "^0.36.3",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.6.1"
}
```

Also here is my index.js with comments showing what I want babel to ignore:

```
/* BABEL DON"T TOUCH THESE PLEASE */
import "parties/promise.js";
import "parties/fetch.js";
import "parties/domtastic.min.js";
/* END BABEL NO TOUCHY */



/* BABEL TRANSPILE THESE */
import "settings/global.js";   
import "settings/tabs.js";
import "modules/helpers.js";
import "modules/modal.js";
import "modules/notify.js";
import "modules/tabs.js";
/* END BABEL TRANSPILE */
```

How can I do this? Do I need another package to deal with this?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How do you compile? It seems it allows compiling individual files: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#compile-files so just compile files you want and don't compile files which are es5 already. Or if you want to compile a directory use --ignore and list all files you want to be excluded: babel src --out-dir lib --ignore settings/global.js,settings/tabs.js,..,etc

Comment: Thanks for that, if i were using just plain babel this approach would work. However I need to use rollup to bundle my es6 modules and ignore doesn't seem to have an effect. I'm using the `rollup -c` command to compile.

Comment: I see. I know that you can use, for example,JSPM which also can produce Rollup optimized builds: http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/static-builds-with-rollup-optimization.html Or I would suggest that you remove polyfills from your app and include them in your HTML because you don't need a module system for polyfills.

Comment: Although i am using polyfills as an example, it could be any es5 code. I want to end up with a single bundle and not have to separate the process by creating intermediary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `exclude` setting of the babel plugin:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: [ 'node_modules/**', 'src/parties/**' ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: I see what I did, my use of exclude was incorrect. Thanks so much Rich!